# When I hit the up button on my app it skips from activity C to A?

Tags: java, android

I have 3 activities and call them

```
    Main startActivityForResult(intent, 1) >
    secondActivity startActivityForResult(intent, 2) >
    thirdActivity
```

When I hit the up button from the third activity it skips to Main and calls onActivityResult of Main but not the one in SecondActivity.

Example of code in Main:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), horses.class);
    intent.putExtra("races", races);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

The result returned to Main:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                races = (ArrayList<event>) data.getExtras().getSerializable("races_horses");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is code in secondActivity:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("races_horses", races);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
```

Why is secondActivity skipped over and the onActivityResult in secondActivity not called?

Comment: Because you put finish() in secondActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called Activites are put on a stack. When an Activity is finished, it's removed from the stack. It doesn't exist anymore, and so doesn't `onActivityForResult` of your second Activity.